# CREATE TABLE statement not working with CHECK constraint

Tags: ddl

Edit: I didn't have the database selected when running the statement.

```
CREATE TABLE animal (
    AnimalID int NOT NULL,
    AnimalName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Category varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    BestPlaceToSee varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (AnimalID),
    CHECK (
        Category IN (
            'Mammal',
            'Bird of Prey',
            'Sea Bird',
            'Inland Bird',
            'Wading and Ground Nesting Bird',
            'Fish'
        )
    )
);
```

Is giving me the errors

> A symbol name was expected! A reserved keyword can not be used as a column name without backquotes. (near `CHECK`)
>
> Unexpected beginning of statement. (near `Category`)
>
> Unrecognized statement type. (near `IN`)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) The syntax is basically correct.  Here is a db<>fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cb4995511d86ec9a404315e702d3307e.

Comment: Well, basically correct for MySQL, the "VB6" of databases? :)

Comment: I am an idiot, didn't have the database selected when I was trying to run.